# MSVS non-commercial license issue

Tags: licensing

Is it ok to write code in an MSVS that does not have commerical license, but later on open the solution file in an MSVS that has the license and then compile / release / deploy using that MSVS?

i.e. Will the non-license infomation be embedded anywhere in the source code, compiled exe/dll or references?

What if there is only one programmer ever?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSVS = Microsoft Visual Studio?

You can use the [Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Default.aspx) editions to develop commercial products also.

You will have to do a one time registration, for free, and then you can use it for commercial purposes.

From http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/support-faq.aspx:

> Can I use Express Editions for
>   commercial use?
>   *Yes, there are no
>   licensing restrictions for
>   applications built using Visual Studio
>   Express Editions.*